# Suppress -Wtautological-compare warning

Tags: c++, clang

I have some code like

```
Q_ASSERT(value_which_is_always_smaller_than_4 < 4)
```

where Q_ASSERT is Qts assert macro. Now clang, when seeing this warns me about it, because the comparison is always true. Nice that it can detect this, but that's the point of the assert statement. Can I somehow suppress the warning, but only in assert statements? I'd still liked to be warned in other places.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The OP wants the warning in other places. `-Wnotautological-compare` will suppress the warning everywhere.

Comment: If clang can detect this, it means `value_which_is_always_smaller_than_4` is a compile-time constant. In that case, you can use compile time assertions (like `static_assert` in C++)  to assert on their value, which is certainly better than a runtime assertion.

Comment: -Wno-tautological-compare

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define a new macro to wrap `Q_ASSERT` and automatically silence the warning using `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored`:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(STR(x))
#define MY_ASSERT(x) PRAGMA(clang diagnostic push) \
PRAGMA(clang diagnostic ignored "-Wtautological-compare") \
Q_ASSERT(x) \
PRAGMA(clang diagnostic pop)
```

Now just doing

```
MY_ASSERT(3<4)
```

should not produce a warning.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable it for the entire file by adding `-Wno-tautological-compare` to the Clang command line (after flags such as `-Wall` that turn warnings on). The disadvantage of this method is that the warning is now disabled everywhere in that translation unit, not just for the `Q_ASSERT(...)` macro instances.

Another, more tedious but fine grained, method is to wrap every instance of the macro that generates this warning with the following:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wtautological-compare"

Q_ASSERT(value_which_is_always_smaller_than_4 < 4)

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: The command line flags `-Wno-tautological-constant-compare` can also assigned to `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` if someone use GNU autotools